# reload 'random' page on document, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, inline

I'm trying to use this reload function which works to load a random post on a blog website, at a set interval.

```
var reload = function() {
  location.reload();
}

reload = function() {
  location.href = location.href
}

setTimeout(reload, 2000);
}
```

I want to use this function, which also works, to send a user to a random post : `window.onload = function(){fetchLuck(a.rel);}`   But I can't get the two to play nice. Not knowing javascript does not help.  But my thought was to make `location.href = "(function(){fetchLuck(a.rel);})";` or something like that. That obviously won't work but any help would be incredible.

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Also, why are you immediately reassigning `reload`?

Comment: It's not too clear what you're trying to achieve but sticking a `javascript:` in front of the value should let you set it to `location.href`.

Comment: What is your purpose for the second statement, where reload is re-defined?

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to load a random post from a blogger website upon the user reloading the page

Comment: Something close to the action I'd like would be to replace <body> with <body onload='showLucky()'> to load a random page every time, but I'm trying to just have the random post load only upon refresh... which is why I've been playing around with that reload function.